Using a section of copper pipe as a stop gap for ground
Can I use a 20' section of an exposed 3/4" cold water copper pipe in my garage by attaching a proper ground wire from the breaker panel on one end and using the other end as a substitute grounding point for a 15 amp utility outlet? There is no chance any section of the pipe will ever be replaced with plastic.

Is there a problem of just adding a ground wire from the panel to the outlet?  While the main water line coming into a house is used as a ground point, I do not think it is code to use a section of water pipe as a ground path for a circuit.

No.
This is a code violation. And you know it is a sketchy idea, which is why you are asking.


"There is no chance any section of the pipe will ever be replaced with plastic."


You don't know that, at best you know that you don't plan on replacing any section of this pipe with plastic but future owners of the house might not be aware of that.
You are running wire to the outlet already. Unless you are running wire thru conduit you should have a ground wire. All Romex has a ground wire included.
If you are running wire thru a conduit, then if you can use that as your ground (assuming it is metallic).
